# From $f$-divergence to its dual: the transformation of convex functions on $\mathbb R_+$ by $f^*(t) = 1 f(\frac 1 t)$

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions, convex-geometry, duality, information-geometry

I would like to understand the relationship between minimising the KL divergence $P \mapsto D_{KL}[P,Q]$ and the reverse KL divergence $P\mapsto D_{KL}^*[P,Q]=D_{KL}[Q,P]$ for probability measures $P$ and (fixed) $Q$.

Both are $f$-divergences
$$D_f[P,Q]= \int f\left(\frac {dP}{dQ}\right)dQ,$$

with respective function $f(t)= t\log t$ and $f^*(t)=-\log t$.

Denote by $\mathcal C$ the cone of convex functions $[0, \infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ that vanish at $1$. A nice property of $f$-divergences, which relates the KL divergences to its reversal, is given in Proposition 2 of *On f-Divergences: Integral Representations, Local Behavior, and Inequalities. I. Sason (2018)*.

> Let $f \in \mathcal{C},$ and let $f^{*}:(0, \infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be the conjugate function, given by
> $$
> f^{*}(t)=t f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)
> $$
> for $t>0 .$ Then, $f^{*} \in \mathcal{C} ; f^{* *}=f,$ and for every pair of probability measures $(P, Q)$
> $$
> D_{f}(P \| Q)=D_{f^{*}}(Q \| P)
> $$

I am wondering whether anyone has come across this notion of duality between convex functions

$$\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}: f \mapsto f^*.$$

It does not seem related to the usual notion of convex duality (Fenchel-Legendre transform).

References would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be related to [perspective functions](https://pcombet.math.ncsu.edu/svva4.pdf).